# SQLAlchemy and mssql+pymssql password fails after a certain length

Tags: sql-server, sqlalchemy, freetds

I ran into something interesting today.

If I use a string with 30 characters in it, I'll be able to connect to a sql-server database. But the second I go to a 31 character string I'll receive a,

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (OperationalError) (18456, "Login failed for user
```

Example code:

```
database_type = "mssql+pymssql"
user_name = "readonly"
user_pass = "j2AZDPBi3ITWnegddQS2xy9HPDLMzXh"
database_uri = "server.domain"
connection_string = r"{0}://{1}:{2}@{3}/Logging".format(
    database_type,
    user_name,
    user_pass,
    database_uri,)

print(connection_string)
engine = sa.create_engine(connection_string, echo=True)
connection = engine.connect()
```

Now that strange part is that if I connect to the database using SQL Server Management Studio I can connect with the larger string.

Why does the password length matter for one and not the other?

I'm using

```
SQLAlchemy==0.9.7
pymssql==2.1.0
SQL Server 2014
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After hitting the same issue myself today, this is caused by a hard limit in `freetds <= 0.91`. It has been patched in the current version on github, but most distributions still have 0.91 or older.

`tsql` is not affected by this limit, as it uses the protocol directly, while most libraries that uses the API has a limit on 20 or 30 bytes for the username and password. Removing all traces of the old library and rebuilding `freetds` from source before reinstalling `pymssql` solved the issue here.

It can also be useful to set `os.environ['TDSVER'] = '7.0'` before issuing statements to get the correct TDS version, as `pymssql` apparently ignores the setting in freetds.conf